# How to properly use msqli bind_param?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble inserting data into a table. Here's the code, pretty straight forward. Yet it always ends up at "could not insert task into tasks table". What I'm I doing wrong?
...
// Add Tasks
if (isset($_POST['addtask']) && isset($_POST['tasks']) && $_POST['tasks'] == 1) {

```
    //Check for empty fields
    if (!empty('task_name') && $_POST['assigned'] != 0 && $_POST['task_type'] != 0) {
      // Set vars
      $entityid = $_POST['entityid'];
      $task_name = $_POST['task_name'];
      $task_status = $_POST['task_status'];
      $assigned = $_POST['assigned'];
      $createdby = $_POST['createdby'];
      $tasktype  = $_POST['task_type'];
      $create_date = $_POST['create_date'];
      $due_date = $_POST['due_date'];
      $reminder_date = $_POST['reminder_date'];
      $task_note = $_POST['task_note'];

      // Create date and timestamp
      $ctime = mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"));
      $cdate = date("H:i:s", $ctime);
      // Reformat dates with time
      $create_date = $create_date." ".$cdate;
      $due_date = $due_date." ".$cdate;
      $reminder_date = $reminder_date." ".$cdate;

      //DB call
      include_once("../inc/db_conn.php");

      // db insert for tasks
      $sqlinst = "INSERT INTO tasks(`entityid`,`task_name`,`task_status`,`assigned`,`createdby`,`task_type`,`create_date`,`due_ate`,`reminder_date`,`task_note`)
                  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
      if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sqlinst)) {
        //Bind vars to prepend stmt as params
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isiiiissss", $entityid, $task_name, $task_status, $assigned, $createdby, $tasktype, $create_date, $due_date, $reminder_date, $task_note);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        // Send success msg
        header("Location: ../add_task.php?succ=1");
      } else {
        echo "Could not insert task into tasks table";
        die();
      }
  }

} else {
  header("Location: ../index.php");
  exit();
}
```

...

Here is the output of var_dump($_POST)
array(12) { ["tasks"]=> string(1) "1" ["entityid"]=> string(1) "0" ["task_name"]=> string(9) "Test Task" ["task_status"]=> string(1) "2" ["assigned"]=> string(1) "4" ["createdby"]=> string(1) "1" ["task_type"]=> string(1) "4" ["create_date"]=> string(10) "2020-08-31" ["due_date"]=> string(10) "2020-09-03" ["reminder_date"]=> string(10) "2020-09-02" ["task_note"]=> string(9) "Test Test" ["addtask"]=> string(0) "" }

2020-08-31 01:58:49

2020-09-03 01:58:49

2020-09-02 01:58:49

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: oh sorry, I thought I paste it on there,

Comment: looks like it now shows the code.

Comment: Make sure you configure mysqli [to throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) so you can see why it fails. If you get "Could not insert task...", then your bind params code isn't even executed. It fails on the prepare.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't know that, let me investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seems that the code was correct in the insert into part there was a type-o "due_ate" when it should be due_date. The way I was able to see the error was by adding this **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);** before the mysql statements and then I added **mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);** and the end of the script. For more information see [mysqli error reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-report.php)